# Jquery events not working in my Angular app

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In one of the html files which gets loaded in my Angular app, I have a little JQuery code which restricts the user input (it's a currency field).

So the html file holds all of the input controls, and at the bottom this code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".currency").on('keydown', function (e) {
            console.log(e.keyCode);

            //removed the implementation...
        });
    });
</script>
```

This works, but I want to use the code in other html files also, and I thought it would be better to place it in another script file.
So to be on the safe side I cut/pasted it in another script file which I know that gets loaded, and when I debug I get to the `$(".currency").on('keydown', function (e) {` line.

But: then nothing happens ie the console.log doesn't get executed and the (not visible here) code to restrict the user input doesn't work.

So I thought it may be a timing issue, that my JQuery event binding occurs before the html gets loaded, but I read `on` is the replacement for `live` and that also hooks in to future loaded controls.

Or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: what return `$(".currency").length`? before you call `on`?

Comment: do you have DOM that dynamically created registered to that event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Angular app is loading these `.currency` items dynamically, then your JS snippet won't bind `keydown` event handlers to those items. `on` is not a direct replacement of `live`. To bind event handlers to dynamically added elements, you need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.currency', function (e) {
    console.log(e.keycode);
});
```

What this does is it binds event handler on the document element itself, which is guaranteed to be present when the JS is executed. Then, when a keydown event occurs, it checks if the event target or one of its parents was `.currency` and if so, executes the handler.

But since you are using Angular, the better approach is to use one of its built in directives or create your own.

In your case, [ngKeydown](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeydown).

Answer (score 1):

```
<tag
    ng-keydown="expression">
    ...
</tag>
```

expression could be simple calculation to calling function with its name
otherwise @Prashant Palikhe's answer will be best

Comment: Ah, never thought of this. Instead of using jQuery to restrict the input, do it in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Probably yes, if your script is not angular related might run before angular has the time to dump the html in the page so no event binding is done.

The way you are describing what you want to do it seems that you have to create a attribute [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)